# How to test resubscriptions to RxJS Observable with TestScheduler?

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs

I have an observable which might throw an error. When it throws, I want to resubscribe to that observable and try again. For example with the `retry()` operator.

To test this retry-logic I would need to create a test-observable which will throw an error the first 2 times it's subscribed to, and only on 3rd time would produce a value.

I tried the following:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';
import { retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Setup for TestScheduler
function basicTestScheduler() {
  return new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });
}

// The function we're going to test
function retryMultipleTimes(observable$) {
  return observable$.pipe(retry(2));
}

describe('retryMultipleTimes()', () => {
  it('retries twice when observable throws an error', () => {
    basicTestScheduler().run(({ hot, cold, expectObservable }) => {
      const observable$ = hot('--#--#--Y');
      const expected = '       --------Y'; // This is what I want to get
      const unexpected = '     --#      '; // This is what I get instead

      expectObservable(retryMultipleTimes(observable$)).toBe(expected);
    });
  });
});
```

Seems that with a `hot()` observable it always resubscribes to the same frame that produced the error, resulting in immediately throwing again.

I also tried with `cold()` observable, in which case I get `------#` - that is, at each retry the observable starts again from the beginning, resulting in `--#`, `--#`, `--#` - never reaching `--Y`.

It seems that there isn't a way to do such a thing with RxJS TestScheduler. Or perhaps there is?

If the `hot()` and `cold()` observable-creators aren't up to the task, perhaps I can create my own... but how?

I also tried adding a little delay between retries, so I wouldn't resubscribe immediately to the current frame by implementing the retry-logic using `retryWhen`:

```js
function retryMultipleTimes(observable$) {
  return observable$.pipe(
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
      delayWhen(() => timer(2)),   // wait 2 frames before each retry
      take(2),                     // do maximum of 2 retries
      concat(throwError('error')), // finish with error when no success after 2 retries
    )),
  );
}
```

But this didn't work either. Looks like the resubscription still happens to the same frame as before.

How could I make this test pass?

Comment: There are two things. First, is that you are expecting an Observable to emit multiple `error` notifications that will never happen. Second thing is that `hot` emits even when nobody is subscribed. So I think you can't get what you expect. Maybe have a look at how `retry()` is tested in RxJS and that might give you a hint https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/operators/retry-spec.ts

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Didn't really find what I was looking for from there. However, reading the tests of `retry()` gave me other ideas and I was able to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution for this. I can use `iif()` to create an observable which chooses at subscription time between two observables:

```js
describe('retryMultipleTimes()', () => {
  it('retries twice when observable throws an error', () => {
    basicTestScheduler().run(({ cold, expectObservable }) => {
      let count = 0;
      const observable$ = iif(
        () => ++count <= 2,
        cold('--#'),
        cold('--Y'),
      );

      //                                                      --#
      //                                                        --#
      //                                                          --Y
      expectObservable(retryMultipleTimes(observable$)).toBe('------Y');
    });
  });
});
```